# An example with, of, or using?

Tags: prepositions

My sentence: *"How to cut fruit? An example **using** Banana"*

I prefer replacing **using** with a preposition, but not sure which preposition to use.

*"An example **of** Banana"* OR *"An example **with** Banana"*

Answer (score 0):

*"How to cut fruit"* isn't a question; or even a grammatically correct sentence. I guess it's a noun phrase. That's not to say that people won't understand it if used as a question, but it sounds like you want to use these words *properly*, without any dissonance for your audience:

- *How do I cut fruit?*
- *How does one cut fruit?*

Similarly, *"An example using Banana"* is just a noun phrase.

Probably you want something like one of these:

- *How do I cut fruit, for example a banana?*
- *How does one cut fruit? Use banana as an example.*

Comment: It sounds like a title, perhaps of a video that's going to demonstrate how to cut fruit.

Comment: yep it's a title. The title can be how to install softwares on Android, an example with/of Whatsapp. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I see. I think I would prefer "How to install software on Android; an example using Whatsapp". But if brevity is valued, you could do "How to install software on Android, for example Whatsapp".